# How do I get C# XmlArray deserialization to replace rather than append to a List?

Tags: c#, list, xml-serialization

I have a settings class. The class has a list of connection reconnect times. There is a default set of reconnect times set in the constructor, which can be changed by the user. When these are changed, and the class is serialized to a file, it stores only the new values. When it deserializes the file, however, the values in the file are *appended* to the default set of values in the constructor. Is there a way to tell the XmlSerializer to **replace** the default values with those coming in from the stream.

```
[XmlRoot("ConnectionSettings")]
public class ConnectionSettings
{
    public ConnectionSettings()
    {
        ConnectTimeoutInSeconds = 5;
        ReconnectSequenceInSeconds = new List<int>() { 1, 5, 5, 20, 20, 60 };
    }

    [XmlElement("ConnectTimeoutInSeconds")]
    public int ConnectTimeoutInSeconds { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("ReconnectSequence")]
    [XmlArrayItem("ReconnectTimeInSeconds")]
    public List<int> ReconnectSequenceInSeconds { get; set; }

    public void Save(string file)
    {
        using (Stream writer = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConnectionSettings));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
        }
    }

    public static ConnectionSettings Load(string file)
    {
        using (Stream reader = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConnectionSettings));
            return serializer.Deserialize(reader) as ConnectionSettings;
        }
    }
}
```

A simple test:

```
static void SaveAndLoad(string file)
    {
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings()
        {
            ConnectTimeoutInSeconds = 20,
            ReconnectSequenceInSeconds = new List<int>() { 30, 45, 60 } 
        };
        Console.WriteLine("Desired outcome: " + string.Join(",", settings.ReconnectSequenceInSeconds));
        settings.Save(file);
        var loadedSettings = ConnectionSettings.Load(file);
        Console.WriteLine("Actual outcome: " + string.Join(",", loadedSettings.ReconnectSequenceInSeconds));
    }
```

Test output:

```
Desired outcome: 30,45,60
Actual outcome: 1,5,5,20,20,60,30,45,60
```

Comment: Easiest way would be to replace `List<int>` with `int[]`. Which makes sense also if you always replace it with a new set and not add values one by one.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. Would you like to submit that as an actual answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<T>` implements `ICollection<T>` interface, and the way xml serializer works with ICollection when deserializing is it calls   Add method on it. That results in the behaviour you observe - items are added to the values you already have there. You can change that by using regular array `int[]` instead. That also makes more sense if you do not intend to add anything there after object is created anyway.